# How to get a return value as soon as it returns from thread, with multiple threads C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, return-value

First time asking a question hope it will be productive:)
I have 10 threads running, and I need the main to print 2 things:

1. A value as it returns from a thread.
2. When all the threads are finished, to print a vector of all the values at the same order as they sent to the threads.

Now, the program prints the "--->" from the function, that means it finished the tread, but I need it to print them from main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//sem_t mutex;

void *myThread(void *args)
{
   int argptr=do123(*(int*)args);
   printf("--->%d\n",argptr);
 //  sem_wait(&mutex);
   //*(int*)args=do123((int)args);

   return (void*)argptr;
}

int main()
{

    int nums[10]={17,65,34,91,92,93,33,16,22,75};
    int TemPnums[10]={17,65,34,91,92,93,33,16,22,75};
    int res[10]={0};
    //pthread_t t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10;
    pthread_t theads[10];

    for (int i = 0;  i < 10; i++) {
        res[i]=nums[i];
        pthread_create(&theads[i], NULL, myThread, &TemPnums[i]);
    }
    // pthread_join(&theads[10], &status);
    for (int i = 0;  i < 10; i++) {
         void *status;
         pthread_join(theads[i], &status);
        res[i]=(int)status;
    }
    for (int i = 0;  i < 10; i++) {
     printf("%d\n",res[i]);
    }


}

int do123(int num)
{
    int k=0;
    while(num!=1){
        if(num%2==1){
            num=num*3+1;
            k++;
        }else{
            num=num/2;
            k++;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

OutPut:

```
--->12
--->92
--->27
--->13
--->17
--->17
--->26
--->14
--->4
--->15
12
27
13
92
17
17
26
4
15
14
```

Comment: Simply print the returned value at the same place where you assign it to the array?

Comment: Have you tried implementing mutex lock/unlock logic? Before a thread enters do123, you block all subsequent threads from executing?

Comment: Bodo-You mean at the end of the first for loop?

Comment: @JoeDavis didn't understand what you mean.. that's what "join" do no?

Comment: 'same order as they sent to the threads' this is usually done by including an incrementing sequence number with the input data to the thread, so allowing the output to be sorted when the last thread has returned its result, or allowing the consumer thread to queue up outputs received 'out of order'until the missing result/s turn up.  Locking thread execution to serialize operation is obviously ineffective as the advantages of multiple threads are nullified.

Comment: Also, consider producer-consumer queues for comms into/outof threads instead of the appalling 'join' pthread cargo-cult:)

Answer (score 0):

The time at which a thread in C joins is not influenced by the time at which that same thread executes nor is it determined by its order. This means that on my system the order which a thread executes and joins in a pool of 10 threads can vary on your system. For example using this modified version of your code (see bottom of post for change notes):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cstdint>
//sem_t mutex;

int do123(int); // Added (1)

void *myThread(void *args)
{
    size_t argptr = do123(*(int *)args);
    printf("--->%d\n", argptr);
    //  sem_wait(&mutex);
    //*(int*)args=do123((int)args);

    return (void *)argptr;
}

int main()
{
    int nums[10]     = {17, 65, 34, 91, 92, 93, 33, 16, 22, 75};
    int TemPnums[10] = {17, 65, 34, 91, 92, 93, 33, 16, 22, 75};
    int res[10]      = {0};
    //pthread_t t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10;
    pthread_t theads[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        res[i] = nums[i];
        pthread_create(&theads[i], NULL, myThread, &TemPnums[i]);
    }
    // pthread_join(&theads[10], &status);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        void *status;
        pthread_join(theads[i], &status);
        res[i] = (size_t)status;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", res[i]);
    }
}

int do123(int num)
{
    int k = 0;
    while (num != 1)
    {
        if (num % 2 == 1)
        {
            num = num * 3 + 1;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            num = num / 2;
            k++;
        }
    }
    return k;
```

I get the output:

```
--->12
--->27
--->13
--->92
--->17
--->17
--->26
--->4
--->15
--->14
12
27
13
92
17
17
26
4
15
14
```

If your goal is to make sure that threads are joined into the array in the main function at the same order at which they are assigned their value in the helper function, I suggest implementing a way to block subsequent threads after one thread has its value assigned to it. In order to do this, you can implement a system using semaphores or mutexes.

Documentation on semaphores: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-posix-semaphores-in-c-language

Documentation on mutexes: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/deadlock-with-mutex-locks

In short, the flow should be when one thread enters do123(), lock all other threads from entering the function. Let all work on that thread be done and have it return from the function and be assigned to its respective index in the array. After this, you should unlock the next thread and repeat.

I suggest giving those a read to better understand how threading works. Good luck.

Notes on changes:

(1) You have to add the function declaration before using the function in your code. You had the definition of the function below where you call it. The compiler does not know about this function as it looks at your code from "top down".

You are losing precision by casting a type void* to an int as the size depends on your OS (16-bit, 32-bit, etc.). I changed them to a size_t struct which will ensure non-negative values as well as account for the loss of precision.

Comment: I apologize for the amount of edits I made to this answer in the short amount of time. I am awful at proof-reading :).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I was miss understood. I know the output will be different in every "run" of the program, I meant to say I need the threads printed twice, at the 1st time when each of one of them is finished, WHEN they finished (that's the "--->") I know this output will always be different, and 2nd when all the finish and to print them at the order they started.